# Show that $\{\pm1,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k, \frac{\pm1 \pm i \pm j \pm k}{2} \}$ is a subgroup of $SO(3)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions

$i,j,k$ are the things we use for quaternion expression.

To show the set is a subgroup, I'm trying to use a subgroup test, which is $ab^{-1} \in \{\pm1,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k, \frac{\pm1 \pm i \pm j \pm k}{2} \} := A$ for any $a,b \in A$.

If $a$ or $b$ is one of $\pm1,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k$, then any product must be in $A$.

So, I would like to show that if $a$ and $b$ is one of $\frac{\pm1 \pm i \pm j \pm k}{2}$, $ab^{-1} = a \frac{\overline{b}}{||b||^2}=a \overline{b} \in A$.

Since I could not find a mathematical way to show this, I am testing with any pairs of elements in $\{\frac{\pm1 \pm i \pm j \pm k}{2} \}$.

However, I don't think trying all pairs of $a,b \in \{\frac{\pm1 \pm i \pm j \pm k}{2} \}$ is the only way to do this.

Is there a better way?

Comment: This is a subset of the quaternions. It is the group of units of so called [Hurwitz quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion), a maximal order in the ring of rational quaternions (I think it used to be called the Hurwitz order, but that term seems to refer to something else). Anyway, it is NOT a subgroup of $SO(3)$. This is because the quaternions $q$ and $-q$ correspond to the same rotation of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: But what's stopping you from brute forcing this? It's not a large group. You can try and identify the rotations as symmetris of the cube $[-1,1]^3$ though. Or simply calculate the square of $\rho=(1+i+j+k)/2$, products $\epsilon\rho,\rho\epsilon$ with $\epsilon\in\{i,j,k\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since the candidate subgroup $A$ is finite, we can just check that the product of two such elements is again in $A$. (After all, $g^{-1} = g^{o(g) - 1}$.)

So, for $p, q, r, s, p', q', r', s' \in \{-1, 1\}$, consider the general product

$$\left(\pm \frac{p + q i + r j + sk}{2} \right)\left(\pm' \frac{p' + q' i + r' j + s' k}{2} \right) .$$

Picking out the coefficient of the $i$-component of the product, which is determined up to a sign, we get (up to sign) $\frac{1}{4}(p q' + q p' + r s' - s r')$. Since all of the coefficients $p, \ldots, s'$ are $\pm 1$, the coefficient of the $i$-component is a half-integer, and the same argument shows that the coefficients of the $1$-, $j$-, and $k$-components are also half-integers.

Incidentally, this construction realizes the group as the so-called tetrahedral group, which is isomorphic to $A_4$.